# Bootstrap datetimepicker returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a couple of date time selector widgets working, but whenever I submit my form, the values returned are undefined. I'm still new to Javascript, and haven't worked with jQuery at all.

My code follows the basic example here: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#minimum-setup

```
<form method="post" action="/requser/direct-user">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="directTrainingDate">Training Date</label>
            <div class='input-group date' name="directTrainingDate" id='directTrainingDate'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#directTrainingDate').datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row"> <!-- Submit button -->
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End Submit button -->
</form>
```

And then back in my Node/Express route, I'm just logging the value of `req.body.directTrainingDate`, and it's always undefined.

Comment: You can log the Network requests from the chrome dev tools, and see the actual POST request that your submit is doing, maybe that gives you more info.

Comment: You put the name attribute `directTrainingDate` on the div instead of the input. Maybe that is why?

Comment: @Trouner, which tab/section should I be looking at? I'm not seeing anything useful yet.

Comment: @Chris, that was it! Thank you.

Comment: @knoll Please ask Chris to place an answer and accept his to help cleanup the site :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for documentation, from my comment above:

You put the name attribute `directTrainingDate` on the div instead of the input.